# J2ME application using GPS and XMLVM

Tags: java, java-me, gps

I have to develop a simple mobile application which sends the mobile's GPS position to a server. The first idea was that of creating this application to run on the iPhone, but I do not know how to develop in Objective-C and my time is limited. Since I am quite familiar with Java development and prefer developing in Java, I researched technologies which would convert a Java J2ME application to an iPhone application. I found about about [XMLVM](http://xmlvm.org/) and wanted to clarify the following issue:

Would XMLVM correctly convert the J2ME together with its GPS functionality? or does XMLVM not support the translation of GPS related APIs and classes?

Answer (score 1):

Once XMLVM has produced the objective-c sources, you can simply compile it with xcode, using all the official libraries and whatnot. As long as XMLVM has interface classes for the iphone GPS api, you can use it. You could also just write your own, matching the official api. Obviously the GPS api probably hasn't been implemented in java so using the XMLVM simulator wouldn't use GPS, but it wouldn't die either.

And actually, I do now recall that you can even send device data to the java simulator. Whether or not this includes GPS I dunno.

Comment: I actually contacted a member of their development team and he told me that till now, they don't provide cross compilation for J2ME.